# How to integrate Flickr API to my android app?

Tags: flickr

What are the steps involved to integrate the flickr api to my android app ,so that I can view my photos in a gallery.

Answer (score 0):

Use [scribejava](https://github.com/scribejava/scribejava) for auth/requests.

More about authentication read [here](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/auth.oauth.html).

Then get tokens, try calls api [methods](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/).

Also you can test methods direct from web by API Explorer (https://www.flickr.com/services/api/explore/{method}.